# Unix bash: Differences on file content

Tags: bash, unix, awk, command, diff

I would like to know whether there is a way or Unix command to know if the content of two files are the same without considering order.

That's to say that the following two files content must be considered as the same:

```
  AAAA
  BBBB

  BBBB
  AAAA
```

Thanks in advance!

Remark: I am aware I could use *diff* or *md5sum* but as far as I understand they do not consider the case I am interested in.

Edit: Since I needed it for finding whether there are at least two files with the same content among a set of thousands of files I post the bash script I am wrote using the @anishsane's answer given:

```
#!/bin/bash
for entry in file-*.smt2 
do
  for entry1 in file-*.smt2
  do
    if [ -f "$entry" ] && [ -f "$entry1" ] && [ "$entry" != "$entry1" ]; then
      file1=`sort $entry | md5sum`
      file2=`sort $entry1 | md5sum`

      if [ "$file1" == "$file2" ]
      then
        echo "Files have the same content"
        echo "$entry $entry1"
        echo "$file1"
        echo "$file2"
        exit -2
      else
        echo "Files $entry and $entry1 have NOT the same content"
      fi


   fi
 done
done
```

Comment: `diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

Comment: I was too lazy.. Will do it.. :P

Comment: @anishsane's answer is correct but given the requirements, I'd probably use `cmp` rather than `diff`.

Comment: Use `sort -n` when a file with 3 lines `AAAA` and 2 lines `BBBB` must be considered the same as the examples.

Comment: In your script each sort/md5sum is done thousands times. Consider making tmp files `${entry}.md5` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your files are not sorted, you can sort them using the [`sort`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=sort) command. Note that this command does not sort the file in-line, but prints the sorted version of file on `stdout`.

`bash` has a feature called [`process substitution`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). The stdout (or stdin as required) of the process is used as a file handle in `/dev/fd/xxx` & passed to the process. (`diff` in example below.)

Combining these 2, you arrive at this solution, which uses plain [`diff`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=diff):

```
diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```